# How to send a string from java client to python server

Tags: java, python

I'm sending strings to Python `server.py` from `client.java`, but there is some error in the string format while receiving into the server. Here are some outputs:

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Here is the server code (server.py):

```
import socket

my_con = True

s = socket.socket()
host = 'localhost'
port = 1223

s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)

c,addr = s.accept()

print "got connection from",addr

while my_con:
    msg = c.recv(1024)
    print msg

    if msg == "quit":
        c.close()
        my_con = false
```

Client code (client.java):

```
// File Name GreetingClient.java
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class client {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
                InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String serverName = args[0];
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        boolean mycon = true;
        try {
            System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName + " on port " + port);
            Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);

            System.out.println("Just connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
            while (mycon){

            String s_to_send = br.readLine();   

            System.out.println("sending " + s_to_send);

            out.writeUTF(s_to_send);
            }

            client.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Encoding error?

Comment: how to solve it? Mingle

Comment: I don't know at the moment, but I recommend you use Socket.IO because it's amazing and saves a lot of the hassle of connections and encoding and such. It was built with Node.JS in mind but I guarantee you there is a Python port somewhere out there.

Comment: I don't have a full solution offhand, but Java encodes with UTF-16 and python strings are UTF-8 by default. So what's likely happening is you're writing the bytes of UTF-16 characters to your stream and python is trying to interpret the bytes as UTF-8 characters. Both languages have encoding methods to allow you to convert encodings and pass them around as byte arrays. Look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with it as well and wanted to post for knowledge sharing - the `recv` function of python returns bytes, what needed to be decoded to UTF-8 string, so the only needed change is `msg.decode("utf-8")` when printing.